# rails authentication using SAML and jruby

Tags: jruby, saml, saml-2.0, jrubyonrails

I'm trying to figure out what are my gem options for Rails user authentication using SAML 2.0 and jruby 1.7.12 (1.9.3p392).

It seems like I could use omniauth-saml but not ruby-saml or samlr. Can anyone recommend a gem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ruby-saml supports jruby 1.7.12. Apparently open-saml would work as well. Those seem like the main choices for jruby and saml2.